# Customising a JQuery Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it inadvisable to add methods to a JQuery element?

eg:

```
var b = $("#uniqueID");
b.someMethod = function(){};
```

**Update**

Just to clarify, I am working on a JS-driven app that is binding JSON data to local JS objects that encapsulate the business logic for manipulating the actual underlying DOM elements. The objects currently store a reference to their associated HTML element/s. I was thinking that I could, in effect, merge a specific *instance* of a jquery element with it's logic by taking that reference add adding the methods required.

Comment: Can you expand on what you are actually trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's nothing inherently wrong with it.  It is, however, pretty pointless.  For example:

```
$('body').someMethod = function(){};
console.log($('body').someMethod); // undefined
```

You are attaching the new function only to that selection, not to all selections of that element.

What you should do instead is to add a new function to `jQuery.fn`, which is a shortcut for `jQuery.prototype`:

```
jQuery.fn.someMethod = function() {
    if (this[0].nodeName == 'body') {
        // do your function
    }

    return this; // preserve chaining
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function would be quite transient. A further requery and it will be gone. You can extend the jQuery object itself by $.fn.someMethod = function() {} and this method will be available for all queries.

```
$.fn.someMethod = function() {}
var b = $("body"); 
b.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create a jQuery plugin. You can define a plugin this way:

```
$.fn.someMethod = function(options) {  
    # ... 
});
```

Call it using `$('body').someMethod();`